# What is a good fish for cooking crumbed / battered?

Tags: fish

I love cooking fish in a batter or crumbed. I usually use flathead which is nice, but I would like to know what other fish works well when being cooked in a batter or crumbed?

Comment: What sorts of fish do you have available? I imagine the answer will vary quite a bit depending on the fish you can readily get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I fancy fish and chips I tend to use either cod or haddock and create a rich beer batter. Serve that with some home-made chips and you're set.

If I want something lighter, but still with a crust, I'd tend to go for mackerel. If that's not available, I'd be looking for seabass or snapper.

Comment: Snapper is an interesting suggestion... will have to give it a go

Comment: Try adding a little lemon pepper mix into the recipe, really gives it a bit of zing :)

Comment: I would be very careful using either Cod or Haddock. In many parts of the world they are endangered and should be sourced responsibly. There are usually other similar fish that are pretty good and which are not endangered.

Comment: The Greenpeace "red" list, which lists fish that you should not buy because they are "endangered" is not so straight forward. Their criteria also includes GMO, fish farming, imported species, and child labour. These factors may be important, but are not actually making the fish endangered

Answer (score 4):

Cod is your classic batter fish, used in most Fish & Chips recipes.  I've used Tilapia in batter before, it works great.

Tilapia is firm and extremely versatile in what you can do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Tilapia works great when cut into inch long pieces: dip in egg batter, plain flour, fry....

Comment: +1 There's a store near us where we can get cheap tilapia. It's proven to be amazingly versatile including for uses such as these.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Mahi, sometimes covered in crushed macadamia nuts. Served with some coconut rice and a mango salsa it's amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Pangasius (or 'Panga') seems to be popular as well these days. It's firm enough to use for your purposes as well, typically aquacultured, and cheap.